# Problem with json_encode() it removes the "0" key from JSON string number in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I need to call this value registered in a MySQL column:

```
{"0":[{"Type":3,"Seconds":-185}],"1":[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]}
```

With this form I get the JSON from the MySQL database:

```
$boosterResultant = $mysqli->query('SELECT boosters FROM player_equipment WHERE userId = '.$player['userId'].'')->fetch_assoc()['boosters']; //response: "{\"0\":[{\"Type\":3,\"Seconds\":-185}],\"1\":[{\"Type\":4,\"Seconds\":-144}]}"
```

I want to access what is in 'Seconds' to modify its value, so I use this form to modify it:

```
$boosterFinal = json_decode($boosterResultant,true);
$boosterFinal[0][0]['Seconds'] += 36000; //the value is changed successfully
echo "Output:", json_encode($boosterFinal); //out: [[{"Type":3,"Seconds":35815}],[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]]
```

Since I run `$boosterFinal = json_decode($boosterResultant,true);` I get this: `[[{"Type":3,"Seconds":-185}],[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]]` 
but I need to stay like this for update later in the DB:

```
{"0":[{"Type":3,"Seconds":35815}],"1":[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]} //good
//bad: [[{"Type":3,"Seconds":35815}],[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]]
```

Edit: Thanks to @A. Cedano (link of answer in Spanish forum: [here](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/351220/problema-con-json-decode-me-altera-un-key-0-de-numero-string-de-json-en-php)), I found the answer:

```
//This is the data that comes from the sample DB
$str='{"0":[{"Type":3,"Seconds":-185}],"1":[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]}';
//Don't pass TRUE to json_decode to work as JSON as is
$mJson=json_decode($str);
$mJson->{0}[0]->Seconds+=36000;
//Object Test
echo $mJson; //Output: {"0":[{"Type":3,"Seconds":35815}],"1":[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]}
```

Comment: If PHP sees that your array keys are ascending ints, it automatically converts them into an array (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Looking into how to get around that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PHP sees that your array keys are ascending ints, it automatically converts them into an array (php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

You can disable this by passing the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` flag as a second param into json_encode: `json_encode($boosterFinal, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)`

Comment: Using JSON_FORCE_OBJECT as parameter did not solve my problem, problem solved  by passing no parameters, like this: `$mJson=json_decode($str);` `$mJson->{0}[0]->Seconds+=36000;` and now the ouput will be something like this: `//output: {"0":[{"Type":3,"Seconds":35815}],"1":[{"Type":4,"Seconds":-144}]}`

Comment: Great! you should type that up as an answer and then accept it :)

Comment: @Leandro I think `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT ` is really the answer, no matter the other setting ([demo](https://3v4l.org/hODsm)).

Comment: I will mark it as solved thanks also @Erty Seidohl, because with that form it also works in some similar cases, although in this case, curiously it has not solved me.

Comment: @Leandro Can you share a test case that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` didn't work. I had an `array` that looked like this:

```
<?php
$array = [
    "someKey" => [
        0 => "Some text....",
        1 => "Some other text....."
    ]
];
```

Using `json_encode` with no flags I got a `JSON` object that looked like this:

```
{
    "someKey": [
        ["Some text...."],
        {"1": "Some other text....."}
    ]
}
```

This is clearly not what I had as the PHP object, and not what I want as the `JSON` object.

with the `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` I got a `JSON` object that looked like this:

```
{
    "someKey": [
        {"0": "Some text...."},
        {"1": "Some other text....."}
    ]
}
```

Which does fix the issuse I had, but causes another issue. It would add unnecessary keys to arrays that don't have keys. Like this:

```
$array = ["Sometext..."];
echo json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT|JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
// {0: "Sometext..."}
```

We once again have the same issue, that the `JSON` object is not the same as the original `PHP` `array`.

**Solution:**

I used `stdClass` for the array that had numeric keys. and It encoded it to `JSON` correctly. code:

```
$array = [];

$stdClass = new stdClass();

$stdClass->{0} = "Some text...";
$stdClass->{1} = "Some other text....";

array_push($array, ["someKey" => $stdClass]);

$json = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $json;

//Output:
/*
{
    "someKey": [
        {"0": "Some text...."},
        {"1": "Some other text....."}
    ]
}
*/
```

This is because `PHP` does not touch the indexes when encoding an `stdClass`.